# binding with property not working in Angular

Tags: angular

lets assume the app component has defined the variable for the value in the input
but every time the event for the button has been triggered the string is printed at empty and the binding doesnt seem to work at all

```
export class AppComponent {
  numVal =1235;
  cssClass= 'hello';
  title = 'AngularAppTest';

  textVal:String='';
  onClickBtn(){
    console.log(this.textVal);
  }
  
}
```

and the html can be either this

```html
 <input type="text" value={{textVal}} />
<button (click)="onClickBtn()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{textVal}}</span>
```

or

```html
<input type="text" [value]=textVal />
<button (click)="onClickBtn()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{textVal}}</span>
```

Comment: this link has the answer to your question: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: well I know i can pass a value from the id off the input but I dont know why specifically this binding doesnt work but I had to include the double way binding feature form angular forms to make it work =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my best representation for you to understand binding,

> [value] <- update html from ts (single binding)
>
> (value) <- update ts from html (single binding)
>
> [(value)] <- update ts from html and vice versa (double binding)

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  numVal = 1235;
  cssClass = 'hello';
  title = 'AngularAppTest';

  textVal: String = '';
  textVal2: String = '';
  textVal3: String = '';
  textVal4: String = 'asdf';
  onClickBtn() {
    console.log(this.textVal);
  }
  onClickBtn1() {
    console.log(this.textVal);
  }
  onClickBtn2() {
    console.log(this.textVal);
  }
  onClickBtn3() {
    console.log(this.textVal);
  }

  updateValue(event) {
    this.textVal2 = event.target.value;
  }

  updateValue3(event) {
    this.textVal4 = event.target.value;
  }

  updateValue2(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.textVal3 = value;
  }
}
```

html

```
<!-- double binding -->
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textVal" />
<button (click)="onClickBtn()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{ textVal }}</span>

<!-- single binding updating model with event wihtout ngmodel -->
<input type="text" [value]="textVal2" (input)="updateValue($event)" />
<button (click)="onClickBtn2()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{ textVal2 }}</span>

<!-- single binding updating model with event with ngmodel and ngmodelchange-->
<input
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="textVal3"
  (ngModelChange)="updateValue2($event)"
/>
<button (click)="onClickBtn3()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{ textVal3 }}</span>

<!-- single binding updating model with event with double quotes-->
<input type="text" value="{{ textVal4 }}" (input)="updateValue3($event)" />
<button (click)="onClickBtn4()">Check Binding</button>
<span style="display: block;">Value: {{ textVal4 }}</span>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obnjxt)

Comment: is there anydrawback from using two way binding with the Angular form for components?rather using any of these event based?

Comment: @PontiacGTX Max try to implement `reactive driven forms` if that doesn't suit you go for `template driven forms` which is the `ngModel`, usually we usually go for double binding, if you want special use cases, you can try the other methods!

Comment: so far i have only used template driven forms, i will look into reactive driven forms

Comment: @PontiacGTX All the best! :)